# Seeking for an alternative to lock the screen without pressing the power button in Lollipop

Tags: lock-screens

I find it cumbersome to press the power button on my Android Lollipop device for locking the screen.

Are there alternatives (like a widget or a gesture) that use some interaction with the touch screen to get the device locked, apart from the automatic lock after timeout?

Also, is there any possibility to lock the screen without the need to install an app?

Comment: Is the device rooted? Which Android launcher are you using?

Comment: Well, if you have [Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) or [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) installed then an easy solution can be provided which would require no installation of an app.

Comment: Double tap the  status bar should work ... Try it

Comment: @LôrdRalfAdolf Yeah, good finding! But that's kernel specific feature and unless OEM provided that option under "Settings" and user enabled it, that double tapping wouldn't work.

Comment: @firelord the asker wants a methode without installing any third party apps so that's all I got ,It worth a try isn't it ?

Comment: @LôrdRalfAdolf Easy! I actually agreed (voted the comment), and also said "good finding!" as an appreciation. I just had to mention the reality and I still would say that your suggestion is the best available on this page as of now, provided that the feature is enabled of course. :)

Comment: @Firelord thanks for the clarification ,I will think of something else there is a lot of tweaks to do that like sweep2sleep (can be added at the kernel level) but I can't think of a stock method to do it ,I will be back with a solution ASAP ,thanks once again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Screen Off and Lock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.katecca.screenofflock) and [Screen Lock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iglint.android.screenlock) app from the playstore. You don't need to press the power button or wait for timeout to lock the screen. Just press the icon and it will lock the screen. You can customize the sounds and animation in which an animation plays before locking the screen.

Comment: Is there any possibility to lock the screen without the need to install an app?

Comment: AFAIK no there is no way to do that in Stock Android.

Comment: Thank you for your hints! I finally installed Lock Screen app from F-Droid Store and use it from the home screen dock now.